# proper way to include bootstrap with angular-generator

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, yeoman, bower

I'm generating an angular app using [yeoman generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) and want to include twitter bootstrap sass.

I see that there are two bower packages:

[sass-bootsstrap](https://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap)

[angular-bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)

Do I need both to use twitter bootstrap with my angular app? What's the difference between these two bower packages?

Answer (score 0):

angular-bootstrap is an angular library that provides directives for bootstrap. It has nothing to do with sass. If you just want sass support, you only need bootstrap-sass.

Answer (score 0):

the way that we include boostrap using yeoman is to install it using bower, and save it to our bower json file. Run this in terminal:

```
bower install bootstrap --save
```

Then make sure to add the various css and js files that are part of bootstrap to your index file.